# No data available

Tags: java, jquery, jtable

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>jTable</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DateController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.DateController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InfoController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/InfoController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DateController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DateController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>schedule.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InfoController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.InfoController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my jtable (jquery) display "no data available". Actually my table contains data. I donk what I am doing wrong 
Please see code below

the model class

```
public class ScheduleDate {
String sapCode;
String projectName;
String country;
public String getSapCode() {
    return sapCode;
}
public void setSapCode(String sapCode) {
    this.sapCode = sapCode;
}
public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}
public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
} 
}
```

the DAO class:

```
public class DateDao {
  private Connection dbConnection;
private PreparedStatement pStmt;

public DateDao (){
     dbConnection = DBUtility.getConnection();
}
public void addSchedule(ScheduleDate sch) {

    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO scheduledate(sap_code,project_long_name,country) VALUES (?,?,?)";
try {
    pStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
    pStmt.setString(1, sch.getSapCode());
    pStmt.setString(2, sch.getProjectName());

    pStmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}

public void deleteDate(String sapcode) {
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM scheduledate WHERE sap_code = ?";
try {
    pStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
    pStmt.setString(1, sapcode);

    pStmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
public void updateDate(ScheduleDate sch)  {


String updateQuery = "update scheduledate set project_long_name=?,country=? where sap_code=?";
     try{

        pStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);


    pStmt.setString(1, sch.getProjectName());
            pStmt.setString(2, sch.getCountry());
           pStmt.setString(3, sch.getSapCode());


       pStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
     catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
public List<ScheduleDate> getAllDate() {
List<ScheduleDate> in = new ArrayList<ScheduleDate>();

String query = "select sap_code,project_long_name,country from scheduledate";
try {
    Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        ScheduleDate i = new ScheduleDate();

        i.setSapCode(rs.getString(1));
                    i.setProjectName(rs.getString(2));
                    i.setCountry(rs.getString(3));


                    in.add(i);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
return in;
}
}
```

My servlet controller

```
public class DateController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HashMap<String, Object> JSONROOT = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private  DateDao dao ;

public  DateController(){
    dao = new DateDao();
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            String action = request.getParameter("action");
    List<ScheduleDate> scheduleList = new ArrayList<ScheduleDate>();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    if (action != null) {
        try {
            if (action.equals("list")) {
                // Fetch Data from Student Table
                          scheduleList= dao.getAllDate();

                // Return in the format required by jTable plugin
                JSONROOT.put("Result", "OK");
                JSONROOT.put("Records",scheduleList);

                // Convert Java Object to Json
                String jsonArray = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);

                response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

            } else if (action.equals("create") || action.equals("update")) {
                ScheduleDate sch = new ScheduleDate();
                if (request.getParameter("sapCode") != null) {

                    String sapCode = request.getParameter("sapCode");
                                            sch.setSapCode(sapCode);   
                }

                if (request.getParameter("projectName") != null) {
                    String projectName = request.getParameter("projectName");
                    sch.setProjectName(projectName);
                }
                                    if (request.getParameter("country")!= null) {
                    String country = request.getParameter("country");
                    sch.setCountry(country);
                }
                if (action.equals("create")) {
                    // Create new record
                    dao.addSchedule(sch);
                } else if (action.equals("update")) {
                    // Update existing record
                    dao.updateDate(sch);
                }

                // Return in the format required by jTable plugin
                JSONROOT.put("Result", "OK");
                JSONROOT.put("Record", sch);

                // Convert Java Object to Json
                String jsonArray = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);
                response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
            } else if (action.equals("delete")) {
                // Delete record
                if (request.getParameter("sapCode") != null) {
                    String sapCode = request.getParameter("sapCode");

                    dao.deleteDate(sapCode);

                    // Return in the format required by jTable plugin
                    JSONROOT.put("Result", "OK");

                    // Convert Java Object to Json
                    String jsonArray = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);
                    response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JSONROOT.put("Result", "ERROR");
            JSONROOT.put("Message", ex.getMessage());
            String error = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);
            response.getWriter().print(error);
        }
    }
}   
}
```

my jsp file (composed of javasscript and html).

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
     
  $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  }); 
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable()({
   title : 'Schedule Date',
                      //  paging: true, //Enable paging
                        //pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
                        //sorting: true, //Enable sorting
            //defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
   actions : {
    listAction  :  'DateController?action=list',
    createAction : 'DateController?action=create',
    updateAction : 'DateController?action=update',
    deleteAction : 'DateController?action=delete'
   },
   fields : {
    sapCode: {
     title : 'Sap Code',
     width : '40%',
     key : true,
     list : true,
     edit : false,
     create : true
    },
    projectName : {
     title : 'Name',
     width : '50%',
                             edit : true
    },
    country : {
     title : 'Country',
     width : '20%',
     edit : true
    }
   }
  });
              $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');    
 });
</script>
    </head>
```

```css
    <body>
           <div style="width: 100%; margin-right: 0%; margin-left: 0%; text-align: center;">

  <h4>General Information</h4>
  <div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in your browser?

Comment: no i am not. just the web page display "no data available".

Comment: debug your code to the point where you are returning data and see  what are you getting in schedulelist.                                  JSONROOT.put("Result", "OK");
                JSONROOT.put("Records",scheduleList);

Comment: user1984524 anything?

Comment: I am trying to debug but i am getting No variables to display because there is no current thread

Comment: Just add a system.out.println(scheduleList); after your call and see what do you get

Comment: when i put the system.out.println(jsonArray). I am not getting any data. It is like my list is empty. .

Comment: Meaning u are not getting anything from your database

Comment: yes I guessed but when  I executed the my DAO class alone I am getting values

Comment: scheduleList= dao.getAllDate(); so when you execute this line you see some data?

Comment: no i am not getting while executing my controller. But I tested my DAO class (where I created my query) and I am getting data. I dont know what is wrong. It is the same code like other  but is not working.

Comment: What is return type of your dao.getalldate method?

Comment: it is LIST. 
public List<ScheduleDate> getAllDate()

Comment: Did U try putting system .out in your dao and see what prints out there. If anything is being returned form there. If not then take the query in your method and run in your db and see what data you get.

Comment: I am getting when I put system.out in my DAO.

Comment: You are getting yeh data and don't see any errors?

Comment: Do one thing instead of this JSONROOT.put("Records",scheduleList); use JSONROOT.put("Records",dao.getalldatea()); and see if it works

Comment: Same thing. No data available.

Comment: Run your application as you do and put a debug in your dao and see if it stops there. Let's make sure you are callin your data controller correctly ?

Comment: it looks like my servlet is not working. because any system.out.println I put inside the servlet even for displaying any value like        System.out.println("etstsslslsll "); did not show. but my controller is well configured in the web.xml

Comment: Can you please post your web.xml ?

Comment: I added my web xml file.

Comment: How are you setting that action to list when you load your page?

Comment: it is in my jsp file. 
listAction  :  'DateController?action=list',

Comment: But how does your data table know that we need to call the list action. Yiu getting what I am trying to say. Like how does it know that's the default action that needs to be taken

Comment: I defined it in my servlet. String action = request.getParameter("action). and I put a condition like if( action.equals("list"))

Comment: But how does your servlet know that action is being set to list

Comment: I am not sure I am getting the question. But it is the procedure I used to for others forms and they are working but for this one I dont know why it is not working?

Comment: are you calling the same servlet(DataController) from other pages?

Comment: no for other page they have they servlet since the data are differents. but they are working.

Comment: Try by adding a "/" in front of your DataController?action=....  in your jsp and see if it makes any difference

Comment: no change. it is the same thing.

Comment: Your servlet is not being called?

Comment: it is not been called..why i dont know

Comment: Did u add the required jquery files and all?

Comment: thank you. I just forget to add some jquery. thank you for the tip. it is working.